# Is this polynomial considered irreducible over the integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the polynomial $p(x)=x^2+x+2$. Its roots are $x=(-1 \pm \sqrt{-7})/2$. Since these are not real roots, one might think to say that $p(x)$ is irreducible over the integers.

However, $p(x)=x(x+1)+2$, so since either $x$ or $x+1$ is even, $x(x+1)$ is an even number, so $p(x)$ is also even. Thus, one might think to say that $p(x)$ is reducible over the integers, since it factors into $2$ and $p(x)/2$, which are both integers.

So my question is "Is $p(x)$ still considered irreducible over the integers?" If so, then what terminology would be used to distinguish $p(x)$ between polynomials like $q(x)=x^2+1$, which would not only be irreducible over the integers, but also cannot be factored as $p(x)$ can be factored?

Comment: $x^2+x+2$ **is** irreducible in $\Bbb Z[x]$ (and in $\Bbb Q[x]$), just as $x^2+1$ is.

Comment: Irreducibility over the integers means that it is not invertible, not zero, and cannot be factored into the product of two non-invertible polynomials both of degree $\geq 1$ with coefficients in integers. So $p=2\cdot p/2$ doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that in a ring $R$, we say $x\in R$ is *irreducible over $R$* if whenever $x=yz$ for $y,z\in R$, then either $y$ or $z$ is invertible.

To say that $p(x)$ is irreducible over the integers usually means that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z[x]$, the ring of polynomials with all integer coefficients. Therefore, writing $p(x)=2(\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x}2+1)$ does not prove that $p(x)$ is reducible over the integers, since $ \frac{x^2}2+\frac{x}2+1\notin \mathbb Z[x]$. In fact, $p(x)$ is irreducible over in the integers as you first suspected.

However, let $S$ be the subring of $\mathbb Q[x]$ consisting of polynomials $f(x)$ for which $f(n)\in \mathbb Z$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z$. What you *can* say is that $p(x)$ is reducible over $S$, since $p(x)=2(\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x}2+1)$, with both factors in $S$. This sense of reducibility distinguishes $p(x)$ from $q(x)$, since $q(x)\in S$ but is irreducible over $S$.

Answer (score 5):

If a polynomial is reducible over the integers, then it can be factored into two non-unit polynomials whose coefficients are integers. In this context, "non-unit" means that you can't choose $\pm1$ as one of the factors.

So $p(x) = 2\left(\frac{x^2+x+2}2\right)$ is not a valid factorization since the coefficients of $\frac{x^2+x+2}2$ are not integers.

It doesn't matter that $\frac{x^2+x+2}2$ produces integers when you substitute specific values for $x$.

Comment: Then what terminology would you use to distinguish this case between $q(x)=x^2+1$? Clearly, $q(x)$ is "more" irreducible than $p(x)$, since $q(x)$ does not have that property.

Comment: This is not quite correct. Irreducible means it can be factored into two non-units. There is no reason these must be non-constant. For example, $2x$ is reducible over $\mathbb Z[x]$ because it can be factored as $2\cdot x$. Both $2$ and $x$ are not invertible in $\mathbb Z[x]$, so this works; it is not an issue that $2$ is constant.

Comment: @CraigFeinstein: "irreducible over integers" does not mean $x$ can only be integer, so $x^2+x+2$ produces odd numbers and even numbers, there is no difference

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks; that's what I had in mind at first, but threw myself off after glancing at Wikipedia too quickly... is the edited version accurate now?

Comment: Looks good, +1.